# Multiple instances of same sensor publishing to same topic

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have my simulated depth sensor configured as follows

model.sdf

```
    ...
    <plugin name="camera_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
      <baseline>0.2</baseline>
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <!-- Keep this zero, update_rate in the parent <sensor> tag
        will control the frame rate. -->
      <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
      <cameraName>camera_ir</cameraName>
      <imageTopicName>/camera/color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
      <cameraInfoTopicName>/camera/color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
      <depthImageTopicName>/camera/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
      <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>/camera/depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
      <pointCloudTopicName>/camera/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
      <frameName>camera_frame</frameName>
      <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
      <pointCloudCutoffMax>3.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
      <distortionK1>0</distortionK1>
      <distortionK2>0</distortionK2>
      <distortionK3>0</distortionK3>
      <distortionT1>0</distortionT1>
      <distortionT2>0</distortionT2>
      <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
      <Cx>0</Cx>
      <Cy>0</Cy>
      <focalLength>0</focalLength>
      <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
    </plugin>
    </sensor>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Whenever I have more than 1 sensor in my gazebo world (created through the Insert tab in the gazebo GUI), the topics published by the sensors get mixed together and the following error message appears:

[ERROR] [1578388163.869961171, 10.928000000]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera_ir/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1578388163.877831571, 10.928000000]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/color/image_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1578388163.888897218, 10.930000000]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/color/image_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1578388163.930333009, 10.939000000]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/color/image_raw/theora/set_parameters]

I've tried adding a `robotNamespace` for the plugin but that does not solve the problem, the same problem persists, just with the same robotNamespace added in front of all the topics.

[This answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8054/ros-plugin-sdf-empty-robotnamespace/?answer=8800#post-id-8800) that says using an empty robotnamespace doesn't seem to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24274/multiple-instances-of-same-sensor-publishing-to-same-topic/) by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2020-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The key is to not use global names for all names

```
      <imageTopicName>camera/color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
      <cameraInfoTopicName>camera/color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
      <depthImageTopicName>camera/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
      <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>camera/depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
      <pointCloudTopicName>camera/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
      <frameName>camera_frame</frameName>
```

(Notice the starting `/` removed)

And follow the instructions [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/) of setting up the group namespace and tf prefix.

Something along the followings in the launch file will do:

```
<param name="robot_description_sdf" textfile="kinect/model.sdf"/>

<group ns="kinect1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="kinect1_tf" />
    <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_sdf" args="-sdf -param /robot_description_sdf -model kinect1 -x -3 -y 0 -z 1" />
</group>

<group ns="kinect2">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="kinect2_tf" />
    <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_sdf" args="-sdf -param /robot_description_sdf -model kinect2 -x -3 -y 1 -z 1" />
</group>
```

---

Originally posted by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) with karma: 78 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0